# Put a mutable buffer of u8 into BufReader.read()

Tags: arrays, rust, io, bufferedreader

Follows on from [this partial answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77071647/595305) to my question there.

I'm basically trying to understand how a particular manifestation of `BufReader` works, which is not `std::io::BufReader`.

The puzzling thing is that (`std::io::`) `BufReader::new(pipe.clone())` produces an object which is said to be type `std::io::buffered::bufreader::BufReader<ipipe::pipe_windows::Pipe>`. Clearly that's not the same as `std::io::BufReader`, which presumably explains why it doesn't implement trait `std::io::BufRead`, and thus the method `lines` is not available.

I couldn't find any documentation on the `std::io::buffered::bufreader` module. But its `BufReader` appears to implement trait `Read`, and thus a method `read`, I think. I'm assuming that in this context this is a blocking method, i.e. it waits until some data comes down the pipe (see details for [std::io::Reader::read](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufReader.html#method.read)).

But I can't work out how to submit an array of u8 which the compiler will accept for this method: these are some of my unsuccessful attempts:

```
    let br = BufReader::new(pipe.clone());
    let buf = br.buffer();
    println!("buf {:?}", buf);
    // let mut v:[u8] = Vec::new();
    // let mut receiving_buf: [u8] = [0 as u8; 1000];
    // let mut receiving_buf = vec![0; 24];
    let mut receiving_buf = [0; 24];
    buf.read(&mut receiving_buf);
```

... I don't care whether it's on the heap or the stack... I just want the thing to work.

NB message signature of `std::io::Reader::read` is `fn read(&mut self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> Result<usize>`.

Comment: `std::io::BufReader` is a reexport of `std::io::buffered::bufreader::BufReade`. Method `lines` is provided via trait BufReader. Do you have it in scope?

Comment: Yes, `use std::io::{Read, BufReader};` is at the top of the file!

Comment: Ah, but `std::io::BufRead` (the trait) was NOT in scope. After I brought it into scope things worked... thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it sprang from Rust language naivety

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The puzzling thing is that (std::io::) BufReader::new(pipe.clone()) produces an object which is said to be type std::io::buffered::bufreader::BufReaderipipe::pipe_windows::Pipe. Clearly that's not the same as std::io::BufReader

It is. That's just the internal name, which is then re-exported as `std::io::BufRead`.

[Here's the definition](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/io/buffered/bufreader.rs.html#50-53)

[Here's the where it's re-exported to `std::io::buffered`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/io/buffered/mod.rs.html#16)

[here's where that's re-exported to `std::io`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/io/mod.rs.html#277)

> Which presumably explains why it doesn't implement trait std::io::BufRead, and thus the method lines is not available.

No. The compiler literally tells you why there's no lines method in the original code:

```
help: the following trait is implemented but not in scope; perhaps add a `use` for it:
     |
1    + use std::io::BufRead;
```

The *traits* need to be in-scope for their implementations to be visible. And while there are traits which are always in-scope (those exported in [the prelude](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/prelude/index.html)) that's not the case of `BufRead`.

> But I can't work out how to submit an array of u8 which the compiler will accept for this method: these are some of my unsuccessful attempts:

I have no idea what that means. `BufReader::buffer` is the internal data buffer, it's where the `BufReader` puts the data it read from the wrapped `Read`: the point of a buffered reader is to "coalesce" reads by reading more than specifically requested, filling an internal buffer, and yielding content from there afterwards until the buffer is empty.

That is because if say you're reading a byte at a time (for a streaming parser for instance) performing a read() syscall for every single byte is ungodly expensive. The `BufReader` will instead perform a larger read than that, then yield a single byte, and future single-byte reads will receive data from the bufreader's internal buffer until it's exhausted which is very cheap (pretty much just a bounds check).

Comment: Thanks for this comprehensive explanation. `use std::io::{Read, BufReader};` was at the top of the file. As a result of your answer and the comment of Ivan C I included trait `BufRead` ... then things work!